# nginx proxy configuration error (config syntax)

Tags: nginx, proxy

Hihi,

below is the config + error it's throwing, can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong. Tried all sorts to get it working to no avail :(

```
server  {
    listen  127.0.0.1:100;

    access_log      /var/log/nginx/main.proxied.log;

    location        ^~/(error_pages|javascript|stylesheets|help|images|xml|graphs|static|media) {
    root    /usr/local/nagios/share;

    location ~* \.(js|css|rdf|xml|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$ {
    root    /usr/local/nagios/share/;
}

location / {

    proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:80/;
    proxy_redirect  off;

    proxy_set_header        Host    $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    client_max_body_size    10m;
```

And the error;

```
Restarting nginx: [warn]: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:29
[emerg]: location "/" is outside location "/(error_pages|javascript|stylesheets|help|images|xml|graphs|static|media)" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/main.conf:13
configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mismatched curly brackets.

The line:

```
location        ^~/(error_pages|javascript|stylesheets|help|images|xml|graphs|static|media) {
```

Has an open-curly-bracket at the end of it but there is no closing curly bracket before the next location line.

What @memoryleak wrote is true also, if you close both of those location blocks, the existing close-curly-bracket will be closing the `server` block meaning the final `location` is now in the wrong context.

The final `location` block also has no closing curly-bracket.

Answer (score 2):

In your configuration file *location* is outside of *server* directive, but the context of *location* is inside *server*:
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location